# what is "the angularjs way" to apply sequential effects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to do simple sequential effects using angularjs. I can do this in jquery, but I just don't know what path to follow to do the same thing using angularjs.

To make things concrete, here is a simple jquery based sequential effect that I would like to create using angularjs. When we click on a tag, the text value of the another tag is sequentially set to each element of an array for a fixed duration. A jsfiddle prototype of this is at

http://jsfiddle.net/mjandrews/U53jy/6/

whose javascript code is

```
var wordlist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
var duration = 200;
var i = 0;

show_next_word = function () {
    if (i < wordlist.length) {
        $('#word').hide()
            .text(wordlist[i++])
            .fadeIn()
            .delay(duration)
            .fadeOut(show_next_word // recursively call until end of word list  
        );
    } else {
        i = 0; // re-set index
    }
};

$('#startbutton').click(show_next_word);
```

To do the same thing in angular, I am frankly not sure even what tree to start barking up.

From my searches so far, I found discussion about chaining promises using the [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). Is this what I should be thinking about? Can anyone point me to a working example? If this is not the best way to proceed, is something like [$animate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate) more appropriate? Is there something else that I should be considering? Any pointers to a better way would be appreciated.

P.s. This question is based on following the advice of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/1009979) that states "And when you come to a problem that you think you know how to solve in jQuery already, before you reach for the $, try to think about how to do it within the confines the AngularJS. If you don't know, ask!" I have a problem that I know how to solve in jquery. I want to do the angular way. I have tried to think about the problem and given my lack of experience with angularjs, I am at a loss and so that's why I am asking.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for $animate? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate

Comment: @AndrewChurch I know of, but have not explored, $animate. It and $q both cropped up as possibilities in my search on this topic. I now have edited my initial question to mention $animate explicitly. If $animate is the way to go for something like the effects I am considering, then great and I will dig it.

Comment: @mjandrews $q is how you apply sequential effects when asynchronous operations are involved, promises are insanely cool but I don't think they'd help you here very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AngularJS way is *completely agnostic* to how you perform animations and DOM manipulations *as long as you keep them in directives*. Once you perform your animation on the component, you can reuse that component over and over with the directive and other directives - and the implementation detail is abstracted from you in future uses. That said, in your directives - use Angular features to help you when you can.

That said, the best practices way to do this with Angular IMO is with CSS animations and use `ngAnimate` hooks in order to detect transitions.

Basically the `ngAnimate` service adds classes to your elements when they are entered etc. See [the documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/%24animate).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example using ngAnimate and setinterval

http://plnkr.co/edit/inSQLEULXdtK3w5XcBoS?p=preview

and another using a directive and your jquery animation code

http://plnkr.co/edit/IAoKNunaXcbMW64O7Foy?p=preview

Comment: Great example. Just what I was looking for.